# Send Email with Zend Mail from ZF1 and i will add a Content Type

Tags: php, email, zend-framework

I can send a test mail with Zend Mail with a Attachement. This works fine.
Like this:

```
        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $mail->setFrom('test@test333.ch', 'test@test333.ch');
        $mail->addTo('test@test333.ch444', 'Test');
        $at = $mail->createAttachment($fileContents);
        $at->type        = 'image/gif';
        $at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
        $at->encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
        $at->filename    = 'test.gif';
        $mail->setSubject(
            'Hi'
        );
        $mail->setBodyText('...Your message here...');
        $mail->send($transport);
    }
```

Now i will add a extra Content-Type which I can read later. like this:

```
Content-Type:test/test-test
```

How can I do that with ZF1?

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$mail->addHeader('Content-Type', 'test/test-test');
$mail->send($transport);
```

Comment: I have a header in the text is "Content-Type: / test/test.test333"
if I have an extra insert with the same name 'Content-Type' then I do not see them in the header. I change the name 'contentType' then I see him again. but I want what they are called the same. How do I do that?

Comment: You can only have one Content-Type header.